# Cannot see my device in Dalvik Debug Monitor

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, screenshots, usb-debugging, dalvik

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [installing USB driver for Micromax A50](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25024/installing-usb-driver-for-micromax-a50)

I have android gingerbread *(2.3.6)* . I wanted to take a screen shot so i enabled USB-Debugging,connected the USB,started ddms but couldn't see the the device/phone connected in the Dalvik Debug Monitor.

What could be the reason for this ?

### [Pdf with photos to what I did and what did i get](http://www.2shared.com/document/AK8aVtH7/android_screen_recorder_prob.html)

Comment: What device? Some devices can take in-phone screenshot before it's officially supported in Android. PS: I've removed the link since it is broken.

Comment: @Lie Ryan My Android Phone. I want to take the screen shot by enabling USB-Debugging

Comment: of course it's not your iPhone, this is an Android website. What's your device model?

Comment: @Lie Ryan Micromax A 50

Answer (score 3):

Have you installed the USB driver? You need to [install the USB driver](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html) to use development tools in Windows, they have to be downloaded and installed separately. For your device Micromax A50, try the following [guide](http://androidforums.com/micromax-a50-ninja/557771-install-guide-micromax-a50-usb-driver.html).

Comment: but i have installed usb driver through SDK manager but not of micromax A 50

Comment: @SuhailGupta: you need the device-specific USB driver; the USB driver that comes with SDK Manager is only for Nexus devices except Galaxy Nexus (i.e. ADP1 / T-Mobile G1, ADP2 / Google Ion / T-Mobile myTouch 3G, Verizon Droid, Nexus One, Nexus S).

Comment: I unzipped the `.rar` file given in the guide but couldn't find _Device Manager_ . Is there something i am missing ? [Contents of Unzipped Folder](http://i47.tinypic.com/2s83hc6.jpg) . [**My SDK Manager**](http://i45.tinypic.com/5vp3ls.jpg)

Comment: @SuhailGupta: the Device Manager is Windows control panel tools, see http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000833.htm

Comment: but i get (this message when i select android_winusb.inf)[http://i49.tinypic.com/20fqm2x.jpg] as mentioned in the micromax guide u mentioned . what is the reason ?

Comment: @SuhailGupta: check the Driver from here solves it: http://micromaxsuperfone.com/products/A50.html Scroll to the bottom of the page where it says "Downloads" and click on the link "Drivers", see if any of the one in that works better.