# Installing USB driver for Micromax A50

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, usb, usb-debugging, dalvik

I have to install USB driver for *`Micromax A50`* .

I have google USB driver installed through SDK Manager, but need a USB driver specifically for this device. To install [this USB driver](http://www.mediafire.com/?a282pa7r50r4c4q) I think, I need PC suite. From where can I get this ?

*My goal is to install USB driver for Micromax A50, so that it gets detected in the Dalvik Debug Monitor.*

Answer (score 1):

[This link](http://www.micromaxinfo.com/downloads/) is the official location to download User Manuals, Service Guides, Driver Software, PC Suites for Micromax devices.

1. Although I couldn't find anything useful there, here's the [Micromax pc suite 1.08](http://www.software112.com/products/micromax-pc-suite.html) link.

   This will download the file "installer_micromax_pc_suite.exe", that once you've executed on your windows OS, it will download the PC Suite from the Micromax servers to a folder on your computer (more or less 60Mb).
2. This is the [Micromax phone suite 2.0944.0](http://www.software112.com/products/micromax-phone-suite.html) link that's more recent than the PC Suite.

   It leads to the same file, and the installation folder that gets created on your computer is the same.

After having the folder on your desktop, just run "PhoneSuite.exe", having your phone connected to your computer.

**Product Page, direct link to drivers and user manual:**

- [Micromax A50 Superphone Ninja](http://micromaxsuperfone.com/products/A50.html)
- [Micromax A50 Drivers](http://micromaxsuperfone.com/products/PDF/A50_driver.zip)
- [Micromax A50 usermanual](http://micromaxsuperfone.com/products/PDF/A50-manual.zip)

Answer (score 0):

It's Easy, Download the Drivers from the Site
 [Micromax A50 Superphone Ninja](http://www.micromaxinfo.com/mobiles/smartphones/ninja/A50) 
 [Drivers A50](http://www.micromaxinfo.com/resourceContent/a50-Drivers.rar)
 UnZip in Safe Location.
 Connect your Mobile With '[Debugging Enabled](https://www.google.com/search?q=Android%20Enable%20Debugging)' 
Right Click on  '**My Computer**' >> Select '**Manage**' >> **Device Driver** >> Find your Mobile as in the below Image

[image: MicroMax Driver Installation]

**Right Click on your Device** >> Update Driver >> Select 'Browse My Computer for Driver Software' >> Point to the Unzipped Location >> Enable '**Include SubFolders**' >> Ignore any Warnings, you are Done. 
 
If you are Using 64-Bit you Cannot install Drivers Provided by them Directly, as they are not Signed. You can Google & find [How to sign Drivers Manually](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=sign%20drivers%20windows%2064%20bit)

*All Device Drivers can be installed the same way if Windows cannot install Automatically.